# Git remove large file - file not found

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to push my `.git` to Github.

```
git push origin master
[...]
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: fc1cc7aed3765ca1e847dee4b7fc831f
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File .terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v1.41.0_x4 is 107.37 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To [example].git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@[example.git].git'
```

Which tells me that

```
.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v1.41.0_x4
```

Is too big.

Fair enough:

```
rm -rf .terraform/
git rm -rf .terraform/
git rm -rf --cached .terraform/
```

Which gives

```
git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    .terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/lock.json
    deleted:    .terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v1.41.0_x4
```

So, seems to be okay.

However, when pushing one more time (after commit), I got the exact same issue I have at the very beginning.

Except this time I have no more `.terraform`, neither in my `.git` nor in my local folder.

What is causing the issue, and how should I solve it? 
I suspect there is some git history to be re-written, but not sure about that. Appreciate any help!

**EDIT**
No, the other SO answers did not help with my case. 
 Please see the answer I gave below.

Comment: Dunno, simple Google Search will not [help](https://medium.com/@mrkdsgn/fixing-the-gh001-large-files-detected-you-may-want-to-try-git-large-file-storage-43336b983272)?

Comment: I did not found this answer by googling my problem, and that was the solution to my issue. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: @phd I have not found any answers in SO before. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked a question.

Comment: Mornor: @phd is showing you how to write a good query: in the search box, type `[git] remove large file history`, and SO will bring up probably-relevant questions and answers that are (a) tagged [tag:git] and (b) have those keywords in them. Then you'll find the linked duplicate.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Croolman pointed out, the following command fixed my issue: 
`git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .terraform/'`

Answer (score 1):

It's because commit you are trying to push still knows about `.terraform/` to avoid it discard the last commit executing a command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Then create a new commit after deleting `.terraform/` from the git history and push it to Github.